# Readin JSon File through ajax

Tags: javascript, json

This is my Ajax Request:

```
$.ajax({     
type:    'POST',
url:   "http://xx.json",
//data: '{id:id}',
//data: '{providername:providername}',
crossDomain:    true,
dataType:   'jsonp',
jsonpCallback:    'loadData'
});
```

ok my request itself if failing coz i need to provide data in data variable above in request not sure how should I send my data to JSON to access the contents.following is json

```
 {
  "loadData"      :   {
       "Facebook":    [
       {
        "email"    :   "karthim1982@yahoo.com",
        "first_name"   :   "Karthick"
     },
     {
        "email"    :    "mallika132-iit@yahoo.co.in",    "first_name"   :    "Mallika"
     }
  ],       
       "Google"   :    [
     {
        "email"    :      "jameson42@gmail.com","first_name"   :     "Jameson"
     },
     {
        "email"     :   "hariikriishnan@gmail.com","first_name"     :   "hari"
     }
  ]
   }
 }
```

Please do check if anything wrong with JSON.
How can I access the Facebook 1st and 2nd Email or Google's first Email or First)name attribute

Comment: Have you tried to parse your JSON string?

Comment: You're asking for jsonp. Is the server returning jsonp? Also, the way you tried to pass data looks fine.

Comment: [i writed a sample answer yesterday, you can check it][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643164/submit-a-form-as-json-no-ajax/19125890#19125890

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for `jsonp` using jQuery, you will get a parameter called `callback` in the GET request, something like:

```
http://your.url/out.json?callback=jQuery123456789
```

What you need to do on the server-side is wrap the ouput in that callback, so instead of:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

You need to provide your response like so:

```
jQuery123456789('{"a": 1, "b": 2}')
```

In your case, it looks like you're renaming the `callback` to `loaddata`. Keep in mind that jQuery will build this function for you, you don't need to define it. What you **do** need to define is the `success` callback that the data will be passed to.

For `JSONP`, jQuery loads the response not as an `XMLHTTPRequest` but as a `<script>` tag and secretly sets up that `callback` on the page. This is banking on you having control over the remote service.

Comment: ok..but wat changes to be done on my ajax request code so i can pull onnly facebook data...if you cna provide sample it would be goodd...

Comment: ok.wat to be done on my ajax request code so i can pull facebook data...if you can provide sample...                                    loadData:({
      Facebook:[
         {
            "email":"karthim1982@yahoo.com",
            "first_name":"Karthick"
         },
         {
            "email":"mallika132-iit@yahoo.co.in",
          }
      ],
      Google:[
         {
            "email":"jameson42@gmail.com",
          },
   ]     
      });
ajax request:var req=$.ajax({
url:x.json,
data: {'x':'1','y':'2'},
dataType:'jsonp',
//jsonpCallback:'loadData'
});

Comment: If it's on facebook and they don't provide a way to add the `jsonp` callback, you're going to need to request the data from your server backend and proxy the data to your frontend so it comes from the same domain as your regular javascript code.