# Model is getting bound but not the individual parameters from json request body in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

Using postman, am trying to post "city" and "country" data.

**URL**: http://localhost:8080/api/Sample/SendData

**RequestBody**: {"city": "abc","country": "xyz"}

**Headers**: Content-Type: application/json

But am unable to retrieve the data instead getting nulls as show below. By encapsulating the properties (city, country) into a model, I am able to see the data.

[image]

Below is the code am using

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[ApiController]
public class SampleController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<SampleController> _logger;

    public SampleController(ILogger<SampleController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Sample/SendData")]
    public ActionResult SendData(string city, string country)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //return
                return Ok("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("error");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //return
            return BadRequest(Convert.ToString(ex));
        }
    }

}
```

Note: I want to send the data using request body and not through query string as the data am going to pass eventually be larger.

Comment: @Nkosi, Thanks, I corrected it. Still have the issue.

Comment: create a mode and use that as the action parameter along with `[FromBody]` attribute

Comment: @Nkosi, Using a model is working fine. But I want to specifically use parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work with individual parameters. When you're using datatype json, the asp.net controller **will always assume it's an object you're sending**.

If you want individual parameters you could remove the json request header and replace it with `text/plain` and change your request body to key-value.

---

There's a similar question here but you would need to install newtonsoftjson nuget package. You'll only get 1 string though, which is the whole json file, then you'll be deserializing it to an object when it gets to the controller.

[POST Json without model and Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256556/post-json-without-model-and-ajax)